# How to install eigen library (or any other header-only library) into flatpak-builder environment?

Tags: c++, eigen3, flatpak, flatpak-builder

I'm trying to incorporate the eigen library into the flatpak build of my application, but can't figure out how to do it properly. So far, I've only used libraries using the `cmake-ninja` as `buildsystem` and that has worked quite well. Since eigen is a header only library, I suppose it should somehow work with the `simple` buildsystem, but I can't figure out how to specify that the `Eigen` subfolder from the source files has to be installed to the `/include` folder. What I've tried so far in my manifest:

```
{
   ...
   modules = [
        ...
        {
            "name": "eigen",
            "buildsystem": "simple",
            "build-commands": [ "install -d Eigen /include/Eigen" ] ,
            "sources": [
                {
                    "type": "archive",
                    "url": "https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/archive/3.3.9/eigen-3.3.9.zip",
                    "sha512": "3b06da583037649ad42190bd018ddf40b85179ad0877ebd7c1ca7b8498a1453eed25919de27d3bb737754086e1513408e7de4a2110d51912f2e5503e1ab7d838"
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
}
```

But no files get copied into the `/include` subfolder, and my application's CMake build subsequently then of course also doesn't find eigen. There must be something very simple I'm missing here.

I've tried looking this up on the web for some hours now, but I'm not even sure yet which documentation might help me here. The [flatpak-builder command reference](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-builder-command-reference.html) seems too brief on information to be useful in this context, and also in the [flatpak documentation](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/) I didn't really find anything that fits my needs.
The tutorials I found only use`install -D hello.sh ...` as build-command for the `simple` buildsystem; some use `npm` commands, which got me confused - I tried `apt install...`, but of course apt isn't available - is there some reference if/which package managers are available in which runtime maybe?.

I understand that in my above command, flatpak builder probably cannot determine the path of the `Eigen` that I want to copy (though there is no error message in the output) - but how do I specify that it's the folder from the sources folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess my original question can be answered easily, since I just realized that eigen actually supports cmake. So changing my module to this:

```bash
{
   ...
   modules = [
        ...
        {
            "name": "eigen",
            "buildsystem": "cmake",
            "builddir": true,
            "sources": [
                {
                    "type": "archive",
                    "url": "https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/archive/3.3.9/eigen-3.3.9.zip",
                    "sha512": "3b06da583037649ad42190bd018ddf40b85179ad0877ebd7c1ca7b8498a1453eed25919de27d3bb737754086e1513408e7de4a2110d51912f2e5503e1ab7d838"
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
}
```

makes everything work.